# Intrinsic Fermi level in semiconductors

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I heard that the intrinsic Fermi energy level always remains constant because it is an imaginary level assuming an intrinsic semiconductor.
However, at the same time, the Fermi level must also have a constant value in thermal equilibrium. If so, the following picture seems contradictory.

[image: p-n junction diode]

I know that in this case the Fermi level should be considered constant, and the intrinsic Fermi level should be thought of as changing along the x-axis. But I can't explain why. Isn't intrinsic Fermi level the only value derived from intrinsic semiconductors, as if the intrinsic carrier concentration has a fixed value of 1.5*10^10 at 300K in the case of silicon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intrinsic Fermi level is the Fermi energy level in the undoped (intrinsic)  homogeneous semiconductor at a given temperature, which usually lies near the middle of the band gap. This energy level, fixed relative to the band edges, is also used in (inhomogenously) doped semiconductor structures like a pn-diode (see the band diagram). There, it is different from the actual Fermi level, which is constant. With the help of this energy level, you can immediately see in the energy band diagram where the local electron density is larger/equal/smaller (than) the hole density depending on whether the actual Fermi energy is higher/equal/lower (than) this "intrinsic Fermi energy level". It can also be used in simpler mathematical expressions for the carrier concentrations.